# ASP.NET Response.AddHeader Closing Window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net HyperLink on a page that when clicked opens a new page in a new window:

```
lnkPrint.NavigateUrl = blah blah;
lnkPrint.Target = "_blank";
```

In this new page is a UserControl which creates a Word document with OpenXML.  I'm trying to present the user with the Word doc WITHOUT closing the new window.  However, the window just presents the document to the user and closes the window returning to the page with the Hyperlink.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" +     masterFileName);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(masterContainer);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
```

Does anyone know why the new window is closing and how I can get it to stay open?

Thanks,

Comment: isnt that because of  `HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();`

Comment: Yeah I tried taking the last two lines out but it didn't seem to help

Comment: I don't understand the problem here... if your navigateurl is as you describe it, the page should open in a new window/tab. Maybe I misunderstood something ?

Comment: I think it's up to the browser.  Essentially the browser is seeing the response as a "file" (by the `content-disposition` header) and is smart enough to know that there's no UI to display, so it closes the new window/tab and just presents the file save dialog.

Comment: Perhaps there's an issue on the client side.  Have you tried testing this with more than one client?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses everyone! Much appreciated.  I've tried it in IE and Chrome and I see the same behaviour.  Bartdude - yeah a new tab opens briefly, it does the work to create the Word doc and then it closes the window and presents the attachment as a download in the window where we started.  David - there is a little content on the page.  All the code is basically in the page_load.

Comment: I think you need one more page. One to show the little content and the other to open the `*.doc`. Perhaps prefer use a `.ashx` instead of `.aspx` for the `*.doc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you clear the content and then transmit a file, there is nothing on the "page" to display. There isn't even a page.

If you want to open a new tab, display a message there and then start the download, you'll have to let the new page call yet another one (the download itself) via JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, that's what I'll do